# Domain resolves externally, but on my IIS server I can't browse to my website

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, iis, domain

Running Windows Server 2016. I set up a domain in IIS. Works fine externally. From home and work I can browse to `myfakewebsite.com` and it works just fine. Bindings are correct.

When I remote into the machine, using Chrome, `myfakewebsite.com` times out. Hosts file is clear, browser cache is clear, command line Ping of `myfakewebsite.com` resolves to the correct IP of the server I'm on.

Even my PHP function `file_get_contents(http://myfakewebsite.com);` fails because it's unable to resolve (the call is run locally by PHP).

When I bind `localhost` and browse to `http://localhost/`, the site works just final locally.

How can I track down why this is happening?

Comment: If you're trying to browse the site from a browser installed on the web server, and the FQDN is being resolved to the external ip address, then it sounds like a firewall hairpin NAT problem to me. Can you browse the site from within IIS?

Comment: Is `myfakesite.com` hosted on your home network or is it in the cloud?  If it's the latter, it sounds like it might be a routing issue. Try running `traceroute myfakesite.com` in the windows command line and see where the packets stop.

Comment: Where's the DNS of `myfakesite.com` and where is it pointing to?